# Download file using Web API Core and Angular 7

Tags: download, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7, imagedownload

I am trying to download file (Image or PDF) with angular but no success.
I did like below

```
<a href="https://localhost:44344/UploadedFiles/IMG_20190314_205925_3be1d2b3-3bac-4184-8468-995d58d5ff80.jpg">Downlod image</a>
```

It is opening image in same tab but not downloading.

So I thought to do it through Web API Core.
For this, I wrote below code.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename not present");

            var path = Path.Combine(
                           _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
                           "UploadedFiles", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(filename), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }

        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
            };
        }
```

Then I called this api with Swagger, then it is working.

But When I did it with angular 7, like below

HTML code

```
 <button type="button" (click)="downloadFile(doc.documentName)">Download</button>
```

component.ts file code

```
 downloadFile(fileName: string) {
    this.documentService.downloadFile(fileName).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

service.ts

```
downloadFile(fileName: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "Document/DownloadFile/" + fileName);
  }
```

When I run my app, click on download button, api function runs successfully but in angular, there is error in console like below.

[image]

Where is the problem ? I just want, file should be downloaded on button click.
please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

For the easiest way to achieve your requirement, you could use `<a href` without invoking angular code.

```
<a href="https://localhost:44344/Document/DownloadFile/file name">Downlod image</a>
```

Generating the above url with your own business logic.

Note, above url is the path for `DownloadFile` action instead of static files in wwwroot older.

Comment: Wen I click on on link, it is opening image in same tab, not downloading. I don't know why?

Comment: @GopalSharma What is your request url? Try `https://localhost:44344/api/Document/UploadedFiles/IMG_20190314_205925_3be1d2b3-3bac-4184-8468-995d58d5ff80.jpg`